# Convergence of the series $1/\alpha x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

We know that $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{n}$$
diverges to $\infty$. We also know that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{n^2}$$

converges to $\frac {\pi^2}{6}$.

Is there any $\alpha$ so powerful that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{\alpha \cdot n}$$

converges ? Is there any $\alpha$ such that $\alpha \cdot n$ is nearly as powerful as doing $n^2$ ?
What is the lowest $\alpha$ such that the series converges ?
Thanks.

Comment: No, it's impossible. Because $\alpha$ is a constant, so you can take it outside of the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $\epsilon > 0$, we have that $\sum\frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}$ converges. In other words: if, as $n$ increases, $\alpha$ is comparable to any root of $n$, for instance if $\alpha = \sqrt[1000]n$, then the series converges.

However, it is also known that by making $\epsilon$ small enough, we can make the sum as large as we want. Therefore, if $\alpha$ is (eventually) smaller than any root (for instance, if $\alpha$ is a constant or $\ln n$, or $a(\ln n)^b$ with $a, b$ constants, for that matter), then $\sum \frac{1}{\alpha n}$ diverges to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\alpha n}&\equiv\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{\alpha n}\\&=\frac1\alpha\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1n\\&=\infty\cdot\operatorname{sgn}(\alpha)\end{align}$$

So the only impact $\alpha$ has is on the signs.

Comment: What if we do $\alpha \rightarrow \infnty $ during the process ? Does it converge at a certain time ?

Comment: What do you mean?  To let $\alpha\to\infty$ in any of the intermediate steps does not equate to anything.  $$\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\alpha n}\ne\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}\frac1{\alpha n}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you mean any constant finite $\alpha$, then the short answer is no. You can just take it outside of the summation, and will get the product of $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ and a diverging series.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is no, because the integral test shows it:

$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac {1}{\alpha x}dx=\frac {1}{\alpha}\int_1^{\infty}\frac {1}{x}dx=+\infty$$

You could ask if there is any $1<\alpha(n)<n$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{\alpha(n) \cdot n}$ converges?

I think the bordering function has not been found yet!

Note: The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{n\cdot \ln n}$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{n\cdot \ln n \cdot \ln(\ln n)},etc$ also diverge (you can check by the integral test).